# Log4Net failing to write to log

Tags: model-view-controller, log4net, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created a new Surface controller for use with my Umbraco 7.1.8 installation. My code is as follows:

```
public class EnquiryController : SurfaceController
    {
        ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(
            MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
        );

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(EnquiryModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();

            // Create a regular expression to remove script tags
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"<script(.+?)*</script>");
            string request = regex.Replace(model.Message, string.Empty);
            request = request + "<br/><br/>" + "Phone: " + model.Telephone + "<br/><br/>" + "Email: " + model.Email;

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(model.Email);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@axumtech.com"));
            message.Subject = "New Website Enquiry - " + model.Name;
            message.Body = request;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                TempData["success"] = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["error"] = true;
                Log.Debug("Custom Error - " + ex.Message);
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }

            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();

        }

    }
```

My problem is my code fails to send the Email and simply performs the CurrentUmbracoPage() method call.

To counteract this and find out what the issue is I have attempted to log the Exception that is generated using Log4Net however this does not appear to be working as nothing is written to the standard Umbraco log.

This is all occuring on a live server. I have published my development code using Visual Studio 2013 and then uploaded this published site to the server via FTP ensuring that the correct SMTP detals are entered into the Web.Config.

The one thing that concerns me and could be a cause of this issue is that this publish process seems to omit the /Controllers and /Models folders from my solution despite the actually being a part of the project. Is this an issue or are these compiled in .dlls?

To me it seems rather odd that the controllers folder is omitted and could potentially explain why the Email is not being sent..

Comment: This should be retagged from [tag:model-view-controller] to [tag:asp.net-mvc]

Answer (score 0):

Have you built your project?  Your controllers are compiled into a dll so do not need to be included in the published site.

If you are still building this page then get rid of the try catch and turn custom errors off so you get the ysod - you want this page to fail with direc feedback

However, to get logging working:

At the top create using ref

using Umbraco.Core.Logging

In the catch:
LogHelper.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, ex.ToString(), ex)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in your log4net configuration (are you calling XmlConfigurator.Configure?). The easiest way to solve this is to enable internal logging to see what is wrong:

enable the internal logging:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Set the output location:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by an error in my model. The model parameter was marked as an int but a text string was being sent through to it by the form. Because of this the model was always invalid and therefore would redirect the page before it ever hit the logging.